# Swapping MySQL Rows

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm testing the data base sakila from PHP. From a list of cities, I want to move one of them in another row where is placed another city. The only way to avoid error "duplicated primary key" is assign a new ID that is not assigned to the target row, move my city to the row id (that's now is free), and finally move the city back to the position that has been freed.

Is there a faster way?

```
$sql = "UPDATE city SET city_id=1000 WHERE city_id=100";
$sql1 = "UPDATE city SET city_id=100 WHERE city='Barcelona'";
$sql2 = "UPDATE city SET city_id=55 WHERE city_id=1000";
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: I think this is the best method.  I negative the value when I do this.